# Randomização HTML automática a cada 4 segundos

Tags: html, random, settimeout

Quero fazer um código de randomização entre 2 números em HTML que aconteça a cada 4 segundos. Como é possível?

EX: A cada 4 segundo mudar o número para um entre 600 e 700.

O código que tenho só faz essa randomização ao clicar em um botão. Preciso que seja de forma automática assim que abrir a página.

Comment: procure por `setInterval` ou  `meta refresh`

Answer (score -3):

basta você criar um elemento HTML e por uma classe ou id, vai de sua preferência, e no javascript criar uma função para gerar um numero aleatorio entre 600 e 700, logo em seguida você cria um setInterval, ele recebe uma função como primeiro argumento e como segundo argumento ele recebe o tempo em milissegundos que voce vai querer que ele seja executado, no seu caso 4 segundos equivale a 4000 milissegundos, nisso é so voce pegar o elemento HTML e por um innerHTML nele dentro da função do setInterval recebendo a função que gera o número random, como eu fiz no exempo: span.innerHTML = random(600, 700)**

```js
const span = document.querySelector('.randomNumber')

const random = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

setInterval(() => {

span.innerHTML = random(600, 700)

}, 4000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    
    <span class="randomNumber"></span>

    <script src="ww.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Achei otima a explicação!
Contudo eu ainda sou bem leigo no assunto... rs.

Como que eu consigo botar esse conteúdo que você adicionou para que apareça no HTML?

Tentei botar no código e ele não apareceu.

O código que tenho com o botão é esse:

<html>
<body>

<id="one">

<button onclick="random()">Random</button>

<script>
 function random(){

document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = rando(600, 700);
}
</script>

</body>

Comment: obrigado! o código que você mandou está errado, primeiro ponto é que o id tem que estar dentro de um elemento HTML, exemplo: <input id="one"></input>, aqui o id está dentro do elemento input. Segundo ponto, para você exibir o conteudo na pagina, você deve criar um elemento e atribuir a ele o que você quer exibir, no caso o número aleatorio, você pode criar uma tag <span> por exemplo, ficaria assim: <span id="one"></span>. Terceiro ponto, você tem que criar a funcionalidade certa da função, vou mostrar em outro comentario.

Comment: <button  onclick="cliquei()">clique aqui</button>
<span id ='one'></span>

<script>

function random (min, max)  {
 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min) + 1

}

function cliquei () {
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = random(600, 700)
}

</script>     veja que na função random, eu criei um método Math.floor, que arredonda o número pra cima ou pra baixo, tipo se der 622.27 ele arredonda pra 622.

Comment: dentro do Math.floor eu coloquei o Math.random, outro método que esse sim gera o número aleatorio, exemplo: Math.random() * 10   isso vai gerar um número aleatorio entre 0 e 10, nisso eu criei outra função chamada cliquei, nela é onde eu vou atribuir o valor do elemento span com o id one, e passar a função random com os numeros 600, 700. depois eu peguei essa função cliquei e coloquei ela no onclick do meu botão, nisso quando ele for clicado, ele irá disparar a função cliquei, que irá gerar o número aleatorio entre 600 e 700 e irá exibir na tela no elemento <span> que tem o id one.

Comment: Cara, muito bom! Realmente o código estava errado... esse seu tá certinho.
Como que eu consigo agora ao invés dessa função de randomização ser ativada ao clicar no botão ela ser ativada a cada 4 segundos?

Comment: Eu acabei de conseguir fazer mas logo depois perdi... não consegui achar o erro. Vou compartilhar com você o código (ele é praticamente aquele que você fez): <span>612 </span>
 <span id ='one'></span> 
 <span class="randomNumber">
   <script>const span = document.querySelector('.randomNumber')     </script>

const random = (min, max) => 
{return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)}

setInterval(() => 
{span.innerHTML = random(600, 700)}, 4000)
</span>

Comment: Tinha botado esse 612 na frente porque achei que precisava de um número de base... mas ao jogar no HTML do Elementor (preciso disso para uma página) a randomização começou a acontecer ao lado dele. Quando fui apagar o 612 a randomização parou.

Comment: Isso aconteceu porque você criou 3 <span>, um com o número 612, outro com um id "one" (que não esta recebendo nada) e por fim um com a class "randomNumber", esse é o span que está recebendo o número aleatorio, pois foi ele que você pegou no document,querySelector, então é nele que está sendo gerado o número aleatorio, por isso ele aparece ao lado do 612 quando se passa os 4 segundos. Para que a função funcione do jeito que você quer, ela deve ficar como eu vou colocar no proximo comentario:

Comment: <span class="randomNumber">612 </span>
         <script>
         const span = document.querySelector('.randomNumber')
         
         
         const random = (min, max) => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)}
          setInterval(() => {
            span.innerHTML = random(600, 700)}, 4000)

         </script>

Comment: Já para gerar um número aleatorio assim que voce clicar no botao e continuar a gerar ele a cada 4 segundos, basta voce criar um botao e colocar um eventListener nele, o codigo será o mesmo que mandei agora no comentario anterior, mas adicionando um botao e sua funcionalidade, vai ficar assim:

Comment: <span class="randomNumber">612 </span>

    <button class="botao">Gerar número aleatório</button>

         <script>
         const span = document.querySelector('.randomNumber')
         const button = document.querySelector('.botao');

         
         const random = (min, max) => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)}
          
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                span.innerHTML = random(600, 700);
             
                setInterval(() => {
    span.innerHTML = random(600, 700)
  }, 4000);
});
  </script>

Comment: Esse codigo que mandei agora tem esse botao com addEventListener, um método que adiciona um evento a um elemento HTML, no caso ali o evento de 'click', ou seja quando esse botao for clicado ele irá executar o que for passado para ele na função, que no caso é justamente exibir no span o número aleatorio, veja que eu coloquei o span primeiro e depois eu criei o setInterval e coloquei o span la tambem, fazendo isso assim que voce clicar a função ja vai ser chamada e o numero aleatorio vai ser gerado e logo depois de 4 segundos outro numero aletorio vai ser gerado e outro sempre a cada 4 segundos.

Comment: Meu amigo! Funcionou perfeitamente... era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Você me ajudou e muito além de ter dado uma aula sobre isso. Muito obrigado e um excelente ano novo. Meu setor é marketing não programação por isso to meio perdido nessa mas deu jeito. Se precisar de qualquer ajuda ai é só chamar tbm... meu insta ta na bio, não tem erro...  vc é o cara!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado amigo! excelente ano novo pra vc tbm, qualquer coisa só falar tbm, se possivel avalia minha resposta lá em cima pra marcar que foi respondido pra caso outras pessoas precisem, já vão ver a resposta correta.